# struts tag questions

Tags: jsp, tags, struts

I have two related struts jsp files. 
I am new to this and a little confused.

1. in #1, for td, where are those value from, i mean firstname, lastname, department.name? are those from fields of the java action or hibernate class?
2. in #2, on line 10, what is employee? is employee.employee.id the same as the one at the bottom of #2 code? also, in the s:select, are departmentID and name from some class?

Thank you very much for your help...

## 1.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%> 
<html>
<head>
    <link href="<s:url value="/resources/main.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <title><s:text name="label.employees"/></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="titleDiv"><s:text name="application.title"/></div>  
<h1><s:text name="label.employees"/></h1>          
    <table width=600 align=center>
        <tr> <s:url id="insert" action="setUpForInsertOrUpdate"/>
             <td><s:a href="%{insert}">Click Here to Add New Employee</s:a></td>
         </tr>
    </table><br/>
<table align=center class="borderAll">
    <tr>
        <th><s:text name="label.firstName"/></th>
        <th><s:text name="label.lastName"/></th>
        <th><s:text name="label.age"/></th>
        <th><s:text name="label.department"/></th>
        <th> </th>
    </tr>
    <s:iterator value="employees" status="status">
        <tr class="<s:if test="#status.even">even</s:if><s:else>odd</s:else>">
            <td class="nowrap"><s:property value="firstName"/></td>
            <td class="nowrap"><s:property value="lastName"/></td>
            <td class="nowrap"><s:property value="age"/></td>
            <td class="nowrap"><s:property value="department.name"/></td>
            <td class="nowrap"><s:url id="update" action="setUpForInsertOrUpdate">
                       <s:param name="employee.employeeId" value="employeeId"/>
                    </s:url> <s:a href="%{update}">Edit</s:a>

                                <s:url id="delete" action="delete">
                                   <s:param name="employee.employeeId" value="employeeId"/>
                    </s:url> <s:a href="%{delete}">Delete</s:a>
            </td>
        </tr>       
     </s:iterator>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

## 2.

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="<s:url value="/resources/main.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div class="titleDiv"><s:text name="application.title"/></div>
<h1><s:if test="employee==null || employee.employeeId == null">
     <s:text name="label.employee.add"/>
   </s:if>
   <s:else>
     <s:text name="label.employee.edit"/>
   </s:else></h1>

    <table width=600 align=center>
        <tr><td><a href="getAllEmployees.action">Click Here to View Employees</a></td>
         </tr>
    </table>     
     <table>
        <tr><td align="left" style="font:bold;color:red">
              <s:fielderror/>
                  <s:actionerror/>
                  <s:actionmessage/></td></tr>
        </table>

    <s:form>
     <table align="center" class="borderAll">

         <tr><td class="tdLabel"><s:text name="label.firstName"/></td>
                    <td><s:textfield name="employee.firstName" size="30"/></td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdLabel"><s:text name="label.lastName"/></td>
                            <td><s:textfield name="employee.lastName" size="30"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="tdLabel"><s:text name="label.age"/></td>
                            <td><s:textfield name="employee.age" size="20"/></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="tdLabel"><s:text name="label.department"/></td>
            <td><s:select name="employee.department.departmentId" 
                list="#session.departments" 
                listKey="departmentId" 
                listValue="name"
                />
            </td>
             <s:hidden name="employee.employeeId"/>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table> 
        <tr>
          <td><s:submit action="insertOrUpdate" key="button.label.submit" cssClass="butStnd"/></td>
          <td><s:reset key="button.label.cancel" cssClass="butStnd"/></td>
        <tr>
    </table>                 
   </s:form>
</center>       
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

for #1 
There is a key-value pair stored in the applicationresource.properties file.This file available in the WEB-Inf folder or its path specify in the WEB.xml file under  tag.
`<context-param>
<param-name></param-name>
<param-value>(specify the application resource file path)</param-value>
</context-param>`

this file contains key-value pair which keys used in your jsp pages.search these label.firstname,label.lastname in that file and you will got the whole situation.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

No. 1. `label.firstName` could be retrieved from any of the value stack which is maintained by Struts. This can be from the message resource or from the property of the action class which forwards to the jsp. Please refer the document below for more information:

http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/tag-syntax.html

No. 2. `employee.employeeId` could be reference to the the `employee` variable set in the Action which forwards this jsp. If you see the Action class which forwards this jsp, you will something like `private Employee employee;` along with the `setEmployee(Employee employee)` and `getEmployee()` methods which shares this variable outside the object. And if you see the Employee class declaration you will see employeeId as a variable in it. This variable will be accessed by the struts tags using the getter method. Here it would be `getEmployeeId()`. I recommend that you refer the link below and see the complete tags which could be used in Struts2 along with their usage:

http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/tag-reference.html

In the `s:select` of the second jsp, an iteration over `#session.departments` happen. Here `departments` could be a list of Department bean over which the iteration occurs. This list is in session scope too. `name="employee.department.departmentId"` defines the name of the `html select` element to be generated. You can see this if you view the html source once the page is loaded in the browser. `<s:select/>` tag generates html select along with html option elements inside it. In this case, when iteration happens on the `departments` list, each `department` object is accessed and its `departmentId` is set as the option element's `value` attribute and `name` of department object is set as the content, which you see in the select element. You can refer the s:select tag reference in the above link for more information.